# Sinatra Routes conflict

Tags: routes, sinatra

in my application I have the following two routes

```
get '/' do
   ...
   haml :home
end
```

and

```
get '/:id' do
    @variable = Something.get(params[:id])
    somethingelse = @variable.some_method
    ...
    haml :show
end
```

If I execute my application using `shotgun` and visit localhost:9393 (the default address and port of shotgun), everything goes normally, i.e. no error message is displayed in the log

If I run the server (also thin is installed) with the usual `ruby app.rb` and visit localhost:4567, then it complains that there is no method "`some_method`" for the NilClass... as if the second route was followed with the empty string as `id`.

In Sinatra documentation it is said that routes are invoked order-wise, so it should not even come across the second one. Am i wrong?

As a test, I changed the second route to `'/:id/show'` and there is not anymore an error.

In both cases (I mean with both shotgun and normal server) the website was rendered perfectly, i.e. in `/` the view was correctly home.haml and NOT show.haml. So the error was present only in the log file. Truth to be told, `@variable.some_method` is invoked directly in the view, and while browsing `/` i got an error from `/show.haml`.

What do to? Is there something that I should do to not encounter this error anymore? Should I blatantly ignore it?

EDIT: The output and the relevant parts of the code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/4585374

Comment: I don't believe this is down to Sinatra's route selection from the info you've given. It would help you if you added further logging, even a `warn` in each of the routes and each view so that you can see what is being called when. BTW, there's a typo in your code for the second route.

Comment: I added the output that I get in the original question. Thanks for the typo, it was only here and not in the actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is a problem I had because of Chrome (see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/A415fHudhhM )

Chrome, whenever it does not get a proper response for favicon.ico, is sending another request and this conflicts with my too generic route `/:id`

**Adding a `favicon.ico`** (even empty) **to the `public` folder** in the root of the project, **fixes this problem**, because now chrome gets a 200 response when asking for the favicon. With firefox there was no sign of this error from the start.

Comment: Glad you got an answer. I didn't get this problem running Safari, so it's not a webkit thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the route without the trailing slash. (See [this page of the Sinatra FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#slash) for more info)

Comment: it was a typo, there is no trailing slash, just  `get '/:id'`